# org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: The server localhost failed to respond

Tags: java, tomcat, apache-axis

I am writing a a webservice which is deployed on tomcat, when the client invokes the webservice, it manages to send the information successfully, but when I am supposed to get a reply I get error messages as follow in my console
I do notice that tomcat crashes and shuts down, every time I run the client I will have to start up tomcat again

```
at org.apache.axis2.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:430)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.sendViaPost(HTTPSender.java:203)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.send(HTTPSender.java:76)
at        org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.writeMessageWithCommons(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:400)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.invoke(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:225)
at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:438)
at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:402)
at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:229)
at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:165)
at ws.test.WebserviceSTSStub.certificate(WebserviceSTSStub.java:184)
at client.Client.main(Client.java:144)
Caused by: org.apache.commons.httpclient.NoHttpResponseException: The server localhost failed to respond
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.readStatusLine(HttpMethodBase.java:1976)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.readResponse(HttpMethodBase.java:1735)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.execute(HttpMethodBase.java:1098)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:398)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:346)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AbstractHTTPSender.executeMethod(AbstractHTTPSender.java:560)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.sendViaPost(HTTPSender.java:199)
... 9 more
Failed at communicating methods
```

This is the log file from tomcat

```
Nov 29, 2012 3:26:44 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
Nov 29, 2012 3:26:44 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
Nov 29, 2012 3:26:44 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
Nov 29, 2012 3:26:44 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper unload
INFO: Waiting for 1 instance(s) to be deallocated
Nov 29, 2012 3:26:45 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper unload
INFO: Waiting for 1 instance(s) to be deallocated
Nov 29, 2012 3:26:46 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper unload
INFO: Waiting for 1 instance(s) to be deallocated
Nov 29, 2012 3:26:47 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader         clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/axis2] is still processing a request that has yet to     finish. This is very likely to create a memory leak. You can control the time allowed for     requests to finish by using the unloadDelay attribute of the standard Context implementation.
Nov 29, 2012 3:26:47 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [/axis2] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@1b3cbc9]) and a value of type [org.apache.axis2.context.MessageContext] (value [[MessageContext: logID=urn:uuid:81669E5CA369177A451354188407165]]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
Nov 29, 2012 3:26:47 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [/axis2] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlBeans$1] (value [org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlBeans$1@1080026]) and a value of type [java.lang.ref.SoftReference] (value [java.lang.ref.SoftReference@41ca9a]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
Nov 29, 2012 3:26:47 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [/axis2] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.CharUtil$1] (value [org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.CharUtil$1@15c4bc6]) and a value of type [java.lang.ref.SoftReference] (value [java.lang.ref.SoftReference@72b4dc]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
Nov 29, 2012 3:26:47 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [/axis2] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.SchemaTypeLoaderImpl$1] (value [org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.SchemaTypeLoaderImpl$1@c001cd]) and a value of type [java.util.ArrayList] (value [[java.lang.ref.SoftReference@1b66f75]]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
Nov 29, 2012 3:26:47 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol stop
INFO: Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
Nov 29, 2012 3:26:47 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol stop
INFO: Stopping ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
```

I can't tell if the logic of the service is broken, or the settings are the settings are not done correctly but I get the impression that the service is unable to find the client that sent the request

Can this be caused by external libraries? I use bouncycastle libraries which I just dropped in the webapps\axis2\WEB-INF\lib folder

I also have a property file and a jaas configuration file in webapps\axis2\WEB-INF\classes  which I access as follows

properties file

```
Properties props = new Properties();
      props.load( new FileInputStream( "C:\\apache\\apache-tomcat-7.0.29\\webapps\\axis2\\WEB-INF\\classes\\server.properties"));
```

JAAS config file

```
System.setProperty( "java.security.auth.login.config", "C:\\apache\\apache-tomcat-7.0.29\\webapps\\axis2\\WEB-INF\\classes\\jaas.conf");
```